# HTTP Requests slow down over time, only reinstall helps

Tags: android, performance

I developed an android app that is used on CipherLab devices (Android 4.4) with a builtin 1d-barcode scanner. The app is used in a small warehouse to keep track of the inventory (user scans barcode, gets current quantity via http request, takes out n articles and makes another http request that reduces the quantity stored in the database)

App worked fine for couple of months, now every http request takes up to 10 seconds. Restarting the app did not help. What did help was to reinstall the app. 
I'm using Volley to make the requests. Example request is below

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getContext());
String host = sharedPref.getString("hostname", "");
String port = sharedPref.getString("port", "8080");
String url = "http://"+host+":"+port+"/article?barcode=" + barcode;

StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
  new Response.Listener<String>()
  {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response)
    {
      JSONArticle a = new JSONArticle(response);
      a.parseJSON();
      TextView tv = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.tvArticle);
      tv.setText(a.Name);
      tv = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.tvQuantity);
      tv.setText("Quantity: " + a.Quantity.toString());
      EditText ed = (EditText) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.edBarcode);
      ed.setHint(a.Barcode);

      EditText edQuantity = (EditText) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.edQuantity);
    }
  }, new Response.ErrorListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
  {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});
queue.add(request);
```

Comment: Volley.newRequestQueue create every time a queue?usually is better create a shared instance of queue...if you try from browser is fast? how many article there are in response?

Comment: thanks, I'll change it to a shared instance. Only 1 article is returned at a time